# How to separate dictionary values into new dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries :

```
d_1 = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0}
d_2 = {'A':60, 'B':30, 'C':10}
```

I've used such expression :

```
d3 = {k: (d1[k],d2[k]) for k in d1.keys()}
```

And as outcome received :

```
{'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}
```

The question is how to perform reverse expression to separate list from this outcome back to:

```
d_1 = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0}
d_2 = {'A':60, 'B':30, 'C':10}
```

Comment: What did you try so far to get the desired reverse output? A basic approach would consist of two nested loops. The first iterating over the dict keys and the second iterating over each item in the tuple which are the dict values basically.

Comment: `d_1 = {k: v[0] for k,v in d_3.items()}`, `d_2 = {k: v[1] for k,v in d_3.items()}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two empty dictionaries (d1 & d2) then iterate over the d3 items as follows:

```
d3 = {'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}

d1 = {}
d2 = {}

for k, v in d3.items():
    d1[k], d2[k] = v

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
{'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the dictionary while adding key/value to d1 and d2:

```
d_1 = {}
d_2 = {}
data = {'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}

for k, v in data.items():
    v1, v2 = v
    d_1[k] = v1
    d_2[k] = v2

print(d_1, d_2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
{'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
d3 = {"A": (0, 60), "B": (0, 30), "C": (0, 10)}

d_1, d_2 = map(dict, zip(*(((k, a), (k, b)) for k, (a, b) in d3.items())))

print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```py
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
{'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}
```

Comment: Very clever but considerably slower than a simple iterative approach

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
data = {'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}

d_1, d_2 = {}, {}

for key, value in data.items():
    d_1[key] = value[0]
    d_2[key] = value[1]

print(d_1)
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}

print(d_2)
{'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}
```

or more generally using a list of dicts:

```
data = {'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}

result = []
for key, value in data.items():
    for i, v in enumerate(value):
        try:
            result[i][key] = v
        except IndexError:
            result.append({key: v})

print(result)
[{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}, {'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dict comprehension with value unpacking:

```
d3 = {'A': (0, 60), 'B': (0, 30), 'C': (0, 10)}
d_1 = {k: v for k,(v, _) in d3.items()}
d_2 = {k: v for k,(_, v) in d3.items()}

print(d_1)
print(d_2)

# {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
# {'A': 60, 'B': 30, 'C': 10}
```